# Warning jsx-a11y/img-has-alt

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, eslint-config-airbnb

I have CRA and i want install custom eslint (airbnb), but after installing it triggers an error

> warning  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/img-has-alt' was not found  jsx-a11y/img-has-alt

package.json

```json
...
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
```

create-app-react - 3.10.10

**.eslintrc**

```json
"extends": [
    "airbnb"
],
"plugins": [
    "import",
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y"
],
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
},
"rules": {
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "jsx-a11y/img-has-alt": [0],
    "jsx-quotes": ["error", "prefer-single"],
    "no-confusing-arrow": [0],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/jsx-no-bind": [0],
    "react/prop-types": [1],
    "react/require-default-props": [0]
}
```

edit: npm said that eslint-config-airbnb needs jsx-a11y v5.0.1

Comment: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/232

Answer (score 2):

I use CRA eslint plugin and when I installed jsx-a11y plugin 5.0.3 I get console warning:

> "eslint-config-react-app@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".

as well with the same warning you get.

I believe you need to downgrade to version 4.0.0. which is still "wanted" version

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1vd8Vva.png eslint airbnb needs eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y v15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you change the rule declaration from `"jsx-a11y/img-has-alt": [0],` to 
`"jsx-a11y/alt-text": [0],` it will work.

https://cnpmjs.org/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y

Answer (score 0):

Since this question and answers are old, i would like to update as to what solved for me.

(As of Aug 2023) The below line worked for me in .eslintrc.json

```
"jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt": [0],
```

I'm using below versions in package.json,

```
        "eslint": "~8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
```

Answer (score -1):

You apparently need to update your node version for the problem to go away.